# Prime products - new pattern

Tags: number-theory

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3,...,p_k$ be all prime numbers less than $n$ (ie $\pi(n)=k$).

Then count of numbers less than $n$ obtained by choosing and multiplying $p_i$'s from above without repetition is approx 60%.

More formally, if $\pi_i(n)$ denotes count of numbers less than $n$, which are product of exactly $i$ prime numbers (that is of the form $p_xp_y...p_z$), then:

$\pi_1(n) + \pi_2(n) + ... + \pi_k(n) \approx 60\%*n \approx 6n/\pi^2$

Note that by definition $\pi_1(n)$ is count of primes = $\pi(n)$, $\pi_2(n)$ is count of integers of the form $p_xp_y$, $\pi_3(n)$ is count of integers of the form $p_xp_yp_z$ less than $n$. And so on till $\pi_k(n)$.

Does this look similar to an already proven theorem or conjecture with prime products?

**UPDATE 8/14/21** --
Based on further discussion, set of prime products less than $n$ mentioned above is same as set of all square-free numbers less than $n$ (sequence [A005117](https://oeis.org/A005117)). Thus all results for square-free numbers apply here.

Comment: @lulu I think the 'without repetition' is the key here, could mean that every prime factor must have exponent of 1.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó  Ah, I read that as "with repetition".  Thanks.  Will delete the earlier comment.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Yes, thanks.  I badly misread the problem.

Comment: @BarryCipra, yes that ratio $6/\pi^2$ looks right..is there an existing theorem that proves that.

Comment: [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_of_Random_Integer_being_Square-Free#:~:text=Let%20a%20be%20an%20integer,(2)%3D6%CF%802) is a proof of that claim, you can find others online.

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding the wording and its relationship to previous comments. Any number chosen from products of $p_i$ chosen $0$ or $1$ time from $\{p_1,\dots p_k\}$ is a divisor of $p_k\#$, which number $\tau(p_k\#)=2^k$. Is the claim of OP and previous comments that when $k$ is the number of primes less than $n$, $2^k=6n/\pi^2$?

Comment: Interesting, possibly related , but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\#\{1 \leq k,l \leq n : \gcd(k,l) = 1\}}{n^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: No, @Keith, $\tau(p_k\#)$ counts all the divisors of $p_k\#$, we just want the ones that don't exceed $n$. And that number isn't exactly $(6/\pi^2)n$, it's asymptotically $(6/\pi^2)n$.

Comment: A related interesting fact is that the probability of a random integer $n$ having greatest prime factor greater than $\sqrt{n}$ is $\ln(2)$. See <https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoughNumber.html>

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks for pointing out where my thinking ran off the rails. That's how I learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting the squarefree numbers up to $n$ other than $1$. If you include $1$ in the sum, you get the sequence [A013928](https://oeis.org/A013928), which includes a reference to a [2007 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/functiones-et-approximatio-commentarii-mathematici/volume-37/issue-1/Explicit-estimates-for-summatory-functions-linked-to-the-M%C3%B6bius-mu/10.7169/facm/1229618741.full) by Cohen, Dress, and El Marraki in which they prove (in your notation) that

$$|(1+\pi_1(n)+\pi_2(n)+\cdots+\pi_k(n)) - 6n/\pi^2| < 0.02767\sqrt n\text{ for }n\ge 438653$$

Comment: thanks, this is helpful! Will be able to upvote once reputation crosses 15.